# Multiple GUIs communicate back and forth

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have two GUIs and I want these guis to be able communicate together. I used Matlab in the past and in Matlab I was using addlistener and basically communicate between multiple guis. I am new to python and I want when I am clicking on the show button on my second gui it update the axes on my first gui. Basically, plot the image on the other gui based on the path I choose on another.

[Here is the image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1lHA.png)

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import 
FigureCanvasTkAgg
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog
from natsort import natsorted
import os
import cv2


class MyCanvas(Canvas):


def __init__(self, parent=None, img=None, *parms, **kparms):
    Canvas.__init__(self, parent, *parms, **kparms)

    self._width = 20;
    self._height = 10;
    self._starting_drag_position = ()
    self.config(width=self._width, height=self._height, bg='white')
    self._draw_some_example_objects()

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

def _draw_some_example_objects(self):
    self.fig = Figure()
    gs = self.fig.add_gridspec(5, 2)
    self.axis= self.fig.add_subplot(gs[0:4, 0])
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top", fill='both', expand=True)
    colors = dict(outline="black")

class MyGUI(Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.title("Drag canvas with mouse")
    self.geometry("700x700")
    """For some reason menu should be added here"""
    self.menuBar = Menu(master=self)
    self.filemenu = Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
    self.filemenu.add_command(label="listview!", command=self.list)
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
    self.config(menu=self.menuBar)

    self._addWidgets()

def _addWidgets(self):
    my_canvas = MyCanvas(self)

def list(self):
    listView(self)


def listView(self):
sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('GreenTan')

dir = fdialog.askdirectory()
filesList = os.listdir(dir)
filesList = natsorted(filesList)
layout = [
       [sg.Listbox(values=(filesList), size=(60, 30), key='_IN_')],
       [sg.Button('Show')]
]

window = sg.Window('Everything bagel', default_element_size=(40, 1), grab_anywhere=False).Layout(layout)

while True:
  event, values = window.Read()
  if event is None or event == 'Exit':
      break
  print(dir + values.get('_IN_')[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyGUI().mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [demo program](https://github.com/MikeTheWatchGuy/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib.py).

Drop your code into the section where it says:

```
#------------------------ PASTE YOUR MATPLOTLIB CODE HERE ----------------------
```

Make sure your drawing is in the variable 'fig'.  It will create a window with GUI options and your Matplotlib plot embedded in it.

Comment: I have tried what you said but it did not work. Do you have any example that you communicate between multiple guis?

Comment: The approach I would take is to back up and attempt to do it with one GUI. Is there a reason you cannot use one of the two GUIs?  What feature is missing that is requiring 2?  Perhaps a change can be make to PySimpleGUI so that it can do what you're attempting in the second GUI.

Comment: It appears you are using tkinter to select the files.  You can easily do that using a PySimpleGUI call to PopupGetFolder.   You can also add Menus.  You are not going to be able to simply glue together PySimpleGUI and tkinter code.  It's not meant to be used that way.  I suggest posting an Issue on the GitHub site if you want further help http://www.PySimpleGUI.com